# how to use blobstore.BlobReader more efficiently

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-io, python-2.7, blobstore

I'm using python 2.7 on GAE, and I'm needing to read files 25 to 35 MB in size. I've uploaded them to Blobstore, and I'm using the following code to read the file:

```
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)
for line in blob_reader:
     # ...
```

My question is, how can I use BlobReader properties buffer_size and position to do this more efficiently. The docs are not very detailed and I don't have a lot of experience with file I/O. The examples given are:

```
# Instantiate a BlobReader for a given Blobstore value, setting the
# buffer size to 1 MB.
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key, buffer_size=1048576)
```

and

```
# Instantiate a BlobReader for a given Blobstore value, setting the
 # initial read position.
 blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key, position=4194304)
```

But It's not clear how to use this to make reading the file faster.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A larger buffer size will result in fewer blobstore operations when reading lines, which will be more efficient. Simply set the buffer size as large as you comfortably can, and you're sorted.

Comment: So the file I'm trying to read from is about 25 MB in size, but the buffer is only 1 MB. Is that going to leave some data unread? I'm wondring b'cos it seems not all the data from the file is being read even though the task is on a backend and so does not timeout.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question. The BloRreader contains or represents a file with about 80,000 lines of text, however I only need to read about 100 of them. Is there an efficient way of scanning or searching the BlobReader, perhaps with some regex, then reading only those lines that contain text that match?

Comment: @Kwame The buffer is just to hold data that's been read from the blobstore but not yet returned to your app code, so it doesn't have to make an RPC call for every line (or character!) you read. It can be of any size and you'll still be able to read the entire file.

Comment: And there's no way to do a regex match on text in the blobstore other than doing it yourself.